# Why does capacitor show a small screen on android app

Tags: android, capacitor

I have an android app, that runs correctly on the web.
I've added capacitor to create an android app.
This has worked well until now.
When I start the android app, the splash screen stays in the background,
and the main screen is shown small inside the view

[image]

(the app is fully functional, only the sizing is problamic).
In this example the orange screen is the main window that should be full screen.
The blue border is a div around the ion-app with a width 200% and height 100%
What can I do to show the main screen full again?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the problem is de splash.9 file.
If I use multiple splash.jpg for each format, it shows as expected.
When I use the splash.9 file it's messed up.
For me is the solution to don't use splash.9 files.